# Wi-Fi 6 WAN DSL router with SSH access?

Tags: wifi, router

I am looking for a router with integrated vectoring DSL modem (100 Mbit/s) supporting Wi-Fi 6 i.e. the new IEEE 802.11ax standard.

It should have an officially supported option to login via SSH and ideally the vendor should have a good  record of OpenWRT compatibility that is alternative router  firmware.

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately, what you are looking for does not yet exist**. (Jan 2020)

Sorry it's not the answer you were looking for but it is the correct one.

**Routers:**

- You can find some Wifi 6 routers, like [this
  one](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B07X9K1N2N/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_U_RmneEb0FZTR1C).
- You are unlikely to find any that support ssh out of the box, but
  OpenWRT would give you this option. However, none are officially
  supported by OpenWRT yet: [Table of
  hardware](https://openwrt.org/toh/views/toh_available_16128)

**Modem:**

There are no combined units yet available outside of using one provided by an ISP.

I would not recommend using a combined unit anyway. You would be much better off getting a good quality modem that is stand-alone.

- My current modem has lasted me through 3 routers now as wifi speeds
  go up but the connection to my ISP remains below the peak of my
  modem.
- Combined units will also be more expensive and outdated sooner.